# Polymer - paper-drawer-panel: y scrolling isn't working

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to make the content of a [`paper-drawer-panel`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel) scrolling.

I am testing it by going to the [offical demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-drawer-panel) in Google Chrome and adding some text to the `<div main>` inside the drawer-panel.

Then I try to scroll down - but it doesn't work. I've tried adding `overflow-y: scroll` to the `<div main>` but it still won't scroll.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paper-drawer-panel` has `overflow: hidden` as [a default](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel/blob/master/paper-drawer-panel.html#L142).

Change it to `scroll` or `auto` or use [`paper-header-panel`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel).

This is [noted in the element itself](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel/blob/master/paper-drawer-panel.html#L36-L37).

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I also had to add position: fixed; to the #drawer and #scrim.paper-drawer-panel